# How to handle json repsonse in Ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the following ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: '/DrawMandrel/RemoveFromList',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ "ID": ID }),
                    dataType: 'text',
                    contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                    traditional: true,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);

                        if (data == "result:success") {
                            alert('REMOVED');
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('ah oh!');
                        }
                    },
                });
```

I am sending the data to an ASP.NET MVC controller and I am getting a response like this:

```
{"result":"success"}
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
```

I cannot figure out why I am getting the alert('ah oh').

Comment: Don't `alert();` things, especially not JSON data. use `console.log(data);` in your `success: function(data){}` callback.

Answer (score 4):

You should change your if statement like this:

```
if (data.result == "success") 
{
      alert('REMOVED');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Technically the raw string you getting would be '{"result":"success"}'.  But you can also change your dataType attribute to be "json" then use

```
if(data.result == "success")
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to write this statement for your ajax request whether it is fail or not

```
if (data.result == "success") 
{
     // do what u want
}
```